# Pure capacitor with ac

Tags: electric-circuits

In dc circuit with capacitor we say 1/2  (cv)v energy dissipates due to sudden busting of charge. But in ac circuit why we don't consider this dissipated energy?

Comment: If the voltage changes on the capacitor, then it's not a dc circuit...

Answer (score 0):

Ideal capacitors are conservative elements. They don't dissipate anything, they store energy.

Their constitutive equation is

$i = C \dfrac{d v}{dt}$,

and the power balance (with constant capacity, i.e. no external actions moving the plates of the capacitors, ...) reads

$P^{ext} = v i = C v \dfrac{d v}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} C v^2 \right) = \dfrac{d E_c}{dt} $,

i.e. the power entering the system equals the time derivative of the energy stored in the capacitor.

In AC regime, you can write the constitutive equation and the power balance in Fourier domain as

$I = j \Omega C V$
$P^{ext} = j \Omega E_c$

Answer (score 0):

> In dc circuit with capacitor we say 1/2 (cv)v energy dissipates due to sudden busting of charge.

That's not really correct. If the capacitor is charged, it just stores the energy until it gets discharge. To discharge you typically connect a resistor in parallel and the energy will be dissipated in the resistor, not the capacitor. Do NOT try to discharge a capacitor without a resistor as this can do real damage.

> But in ac circuit why we don't consider this dissipated energy?

In the loss free case no energy gets dissipated. The energy just moves back and forth between the capacitor and the source but nothing gets turned into heat. In practice there is always a finite resistance specifically in the source itself so the loss-free case doesn't actually exist